# Set htaccess rewrite for specific days of the week

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had this working before, but it looks like it's not working now.

I'm trying to redirect to a URL within my `htaccess` file between Friday and Saturday.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} >4
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} <0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/other-page/$1 [NC,L]
```

I had tested this out before and it *was* working to the best of my knowledge, but now it appears it doesn't.

Basically, I'm trying to get it to redirect on Friday and Saturday only, but I'm not sure if I have the days of the week set correctly. I could have swore that the day of 0 was set to be Sunday, but I might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

`%{TIME_WDAY}` variable  represents  day of week  from 0 to 6 . So if you want to match `friday` in your Condition  then the `RewriteCond` will look like `RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =5` .

To redirect the site on `friday` and `Saturday` only ,You need to use 2 conditions and combine them using `[OR]` condition flag.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =5 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =6
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/other-page/$1 [NC,L]
```

You can also use a single condition

```
 RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} >4
```

This checks if the `%{TIME_WDAY}` is greater than `4`.
In this case this matches 5 and 6 .

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks! This makes more sense now. I'll combine them using the OR condition flag. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that the day to integer conversion is NOT compatible with what you can expect to find in most programming language, for example this is neither https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday nor https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday